# What is the meaning of the phrase 'for the purpose of' in legal context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage, phrase-usage, legalese

I've come across this phrase many times in contracts and other legal instruments of similar nature, and can't seem to understand what its actual meaning is. For example,

> **For the purpose of this Agreement,** the term «investments» means every
> kind of assets and rights related to investments made by investors.

> **For the Purpose of this Agreement**, the terms Disclosing Party and
> Receiving Party shall each comprise each Party's Affiliated Companies.

The meaning of the phrase, according to Macmillan, is "when considering one particular thing." This doesn't make sense to me when applying this meaning to the above text. Are there other meanings of the phrase that I don't know of? I think the phrase could mean "as used in" because, in my interpretation, the phrase is used to limit the context in which the meaning of a particular term is applied (which, in the above cases, is "this agreement").

Comment: The definition "when considering one particular thing" works here: When considering this agreement.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: It just means *within* this document. We define A within this agreement to mean ABC. Contracts are shortened or specialized by the technique, and things are explicit.

Answer (score 1):

This is used when the document is defining terms. It's stating clearly that whenever the terms are used in this document, they should only be interpreted with these meanings. So it does essentially mean "as used in".

I believe it should be understood as short for "For the purpose of understanding this agreement". This sense of "purpose" means an intended goal.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!